# MySQL @variable

Tags: sql, mysql, variables, triggers, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to set up a MySQL trigger, but I can't figure out how exactly to get what I want done. I think I need to set up a MySQL @variable but what I've tried hasn't worked and I have not been able to find a good resource figure it out. I change the delimiter in phpMyAdmin, and the comment in the below is not used in the actual query.

```
CREATE TRIGGER coroner AFTER INSERT ON events
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE teams SET live = live-1 WHERE id = NEW.victim;
UPDATE teams SET score = score+NEW.value WHERE id = NEW.shooter;
UPDATE teams SET last_active = NEW.time WHERE id = NEW.shooter OR id = NEW.victim;
// up to here all works fine
IF (SELECT live FROM teams WHERE id = NEW.victim) = 0 THEN
UPDATE teams SET slot = slot-1 WHERE slot > OLD.slot;
ENDIF;
END
```

What I'm actually doing here is taking a team arranged in a circle, and when the last player of the team has been eliminated, I'm closing the circle up without it.

Here is the error message from phpMyAdmin:

> #1363 - There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger

thanks for any help

---

new attempt:

```
CREATE TRIGGER coroner AFTER INSERT ON events
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE teams SET live = live-1 WHERE id = NEW.victim;
UPDATE teams SET score = score+NEW.value WHERE id = NEW.shooter;
UPDATE teams SET last_active = NEW.time WHERE id = NEW.shooter OR id = NEW.victim;
SET @pivot := (SELECT slot FROM teams WHERE id = NEW.victim);
IF (SELECT live FROM teams WHERE id = NEW.victim) = 0 THEN
UPDATE teams SET slot = slot+1 WHERE slot < @pivot;
ENDIF;
END
```

error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near '; END' at line 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `ENDIF` keyword in the trigger language.  Use `END IF` (with a space in it) instead.

You can review the syntax documentation for the [`IF` Statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/if-statement.html).